# Linq orderby and distinct

Tags: linq

I have a table set up as follows:

```
Section SectionOrder
Sect1     1 
Sect2     2 
Sect3     3 
Sect3     3 
Sect1     1
Sect2     2
```

I need to pull out distinct sections in correct section order. Here is the linq that I'm using, but it's not putting them in the correct order for some reason.

```
var myVar = (from x in context.Documents 
             orderby x.SectionOrder ascending
             select x.Section).Distinct();
```

I then want to be able to loop through myVar and put each item in a list as follows:

```
foreach (var t in myVar)
        {
             listOfDocTypeSections.Add(t);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of `OrderBy` and `Distinct` matters: while `OrderBy` produced an ordered sequence, `Distinct` doesn't. You need to put `Distinct` first, and then use `OrderBy`. However, since you take `Distinct` on one attribute, and order on the other attribute, you need to do it differently:

```
var myVar = context
    .Documents
    .GroupBy(x => x => x.Section) // This replaces Distinct()
    .OrderBy(g => g.FirstOrDefault().SectionOrder) // There will be no default
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

This approach replaces `Distinct` with `GroupBy`, and orders on the first `SectionOrder` item of a group. You can change this sorting strategy to sort on some other item within the `Section`, say, `Min` or `Max` value of `SectionOrder`:

```
var myVar = context
    .Documents
    .GroupBy(x => x => x.Section)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Max(x => x.SectionOrder))
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: i'm getting this error with your query: base {System.SystemException} = {"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."}

Comment: @JAck28 That's strange. You can use `FirstOrDefault`, too, because there will always be at least one item there.

Comment: @JAck28 Also you should be able to do `listOfDocTypeSections.AddRange(myVar)` instead of a `foreach` loop.

Comment: The firstordefault() worked! Thanks for pointing out that I can use .AddRange - I didn't know about that.